# Adding custom className to <NavItem>

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using `react-bootstrap` and want to add a customized className on the tag .I followed this link: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html, but it doesn't provide a property to add additional classNames. Below are all the properties that can be used for this tag. Is there some way to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all properties are listed there, and you should be able to use `className` on the `<NavItem>` directly.

If you have a look at (a snippet of) the source code of `NavItem.js` of `react-bootstrap`, it looks like this:

```
return _react2['default'].createElement(
  'li',
  {
    role: 'presentation',
    className: (0, _classnames2['default'])(className, { active: active, disabled: disabled }),
    style: style
  },
  _react2['default'].createElement(_SafeAnchor2['default'], (0, _extends3['default'])({}, props, {
    disabled: disabled,
    onClick: (0, _createChainedFunction2['default'])(onClick, this.handleClick)
  }))
);
```

As you can see, it creates a new `<li>` element with the props `role`, `style`, and also `className`. The `disabled` and `onClick` props are passed on to an `<a>` tag which is a child of the above `<li>` element.

---

So just use:

```
<NavItem className="my-class" active={true}>Example</NavItem>
```

this will render:

```
<li role="presentation" class="my-class active">
  <a role="button" href="#">Example</a>
</li>
```